# Is there an HTML/CSS/Javascript web editor plugin to showcase private frameworks?

Tags: jsfiddle, plunker

I use JSFiddle, Plunkr, Codepen, etc to test code with **publicly** available frameworks (angular, bootstrap, etc). I'd like to host something on my corporate network to permit usage of **private** frameworks.

I'd like to create a place where devs can isolate their code and/or play with private framework components. Does anyone know of a project/tool that creates HTML, CSS, JS and Results panes with syntax highlighting, a run button, etc that I can host on my corporate network?

Comment: If my question was unclear, please leave a comment so I can try to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @adamdport, I'm the creator of Plunker. I would be happy to discuss setting up an instance for private, internal usage. Please contact me at filearts on gmail.